# My else if's don't work

Tags: if-statement, actionscript-3

I have no idea why my `else if`'s aren't working!!!

```
 var workSurvival:Number = 0;
    var work:int = parseInt(work_txt.text);

if(work < 60 > 0){
    workSurvival = work*12;
        trace("work 1-" + workSurvival);
}else if(work < 120 > 60){
    workSurvival = work*25;
        trace("work 2-" + workSurvival);
        trace(work);
}else if(work == 120){
    bestScore -= 1;
        trace("Good Score!");
}else if(work < 200 > 120){
    workSurvival = work*8;
        trace("work 3-" + workSurvival);
}else if(work < 401 > 200){
    workSurvival = work*4;
        trace("work 4-" + workSurvival);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`if(work < 60 > 0)` is not a valid IF statement.  You need to rewrite it to be

```
if(work > 0 && work < 60)
```

The same goes for every other statement here.

Comment: *sigh*...those little mistakes will be the end of me :(

Comment: Off topic… but, please stop suggesting minor edits. If you want to help with retagging but don't have 2k (or 10k for large ones) make sure you also improve other parts of the post.

Comment: @howrad You could ask on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) for somebody to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what howrad said: `work < x > y` is equivalent to `(work < x) > y`, so during evaluation it will end up as `true > y` or `false < y` (after `work < x` is evaluated) and not exhibit the desired range behavior ..

Now, how *I* would write it:

```
if(work < 60){
}else if(work < 120){
}else if(work == 120){
}else if(work < 200){
}else if(work < 401){
}else{
}
```

That is, "inch along": this works because the conditionals go from specific to general across the range and the first matching conditional will terminate the sequence of checks.

Comment: Sometimes I wish it would let you write statements like `if(0 < work < 60)`

Comment: @howrad Sometimes it would be really nice to have a "betweens" operator .. and general operator overloading. There is at least one language that allows such syntax, but I've forgotten which.

Answer (score 0):

your conditions inside the if statements are incorrect

change them to

`if(work>0&&work<60)` instead of `if(work < 60 > 0)`

`else if(work>60&&work<120)` instead of `else if(work < 120 > 60)`

`else if(work>120&&work<200)` instead of `else if(work < 200 > 120)`

`if(work>200&&work<401)` instead of `else if(work < 401 > 200)`

and your code should work fine